# thrown: undefined after using middleware in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm using jest to test react testing with router and I used applyMiddleware to deal with async function in react code I'm getting below error after using middleware after npm run test and the test fails
Test Code (Jest):

```
import React from "react";

import Results from '../Results'

import { render,cleanup} from '@testing-library/react';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import "@testing-library/jest-dom"

import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

function reducer(state, action) {

   switch (action) {

      default:
        return state

    }

}

function renderWithRedux(

    component,

    { initialState, store = createStore(reducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk)) } = {}

    ) {

    return {

        ...render(<Provider store={store}><Router>{component}</Router></Provider>)


    }
}


afterEach(cleanup);

test("Testing result",async () => {

    const dispatch = jest.fn();

    const { getByTestId, getByText } = renderWithRedux(<Results dispatch={dispatch}/>);

});
```

After using the middlewaares I'm getting

Error received:

```
thrown: undefined

 test("Testing result",() => { .....
 ^

 Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
 Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. There's nothing in the code you posted suggests where `thrown: undefined` comes from. As it can be noticed, `undefined` error is not very descriptive. That the error refers to `test` line likely means that source maps went wrong. And FWIW, you won't be able to test a router as is in Jest, it's not a browser. Is there are a reason why it's `return { ...render() }` and not `return render()`? In case you don't know that for sure, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for message a I also tried return render() but I'm getting this error when i try to render the dom-
(node:15156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Caught error after test environment was torn down
Cannot read property 'body' of null
 FAIL  src/modules/reprice-results/components/__test__/Results.test.js
  × Testing result (33ms)
  ● Testing result
 thrown: undefined
afterEach(cleanup);
test("Testing result",async () => {
^
at new Spec (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/reprice-

Comment: This is the problem with this approach, there are multiple units involved in integration test - Redux, router, component, probably something in component implementation because it wasn't shown. You don't know which one fails if the error doesn't explain that. The problem cannot be solved without MCVE. Try to simplify the test and remove units one by one to make the test pass, only you can do that at this moment. The only recommendation here is to remove `afterEach(cleanup)` because this is already done by Jest, could be responsible for unhandled rejection but not sure about another error